# Measuring a fixie/single speed bike

Tags: bike-fit, single-speed, fixed-gear

Do fixie bikes measure like classic road bikes? i.e: https://www.ebicycles.com/bicycle-tools/measure-frame/road-bike/classic

Or only up to the top tube? (without the part of the seat tube that's above the top tube)

Comment: Classic road bikes are usually measured to top of top tube or center of top tube. Or my favourite, "where the center of top tube would be if it was a standard-sized tube with top at the same height of this oversized tube". Or maybe to seat clamp, it really depends on who does the measuring.

Comment: @ojs yeah so how can I know if this frame with 54" tube is really the same size as my 54" frame?

Comment: Ask the seller how the measurement is taken and measure your own bike yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Fixie/single speeds have the same measurements as any other bike.

Most fixies/single speeds have geometries that are like old road bikes or hybrids depending on how they're built (obviously a fixie built from an old road bike will have an old road bike geometry!). So, you need to take that into account and preferably try the bike before you buy it. You may find you want a longer top tube or shorter top tube or whatever.